# Issue in clone table in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to take a clone of a div(which has table and its contents)to another div.The data get copied,but when i try edit the cloned table data,the main table data also getting changed,but i don't want the main table data to be changed.It would be great if someone help me in changing the table name from main div to clone div Can any one help me with this.?

```
<div id="maindiv" class="ui-widget"
    style="width: 100%; height: 275px; overflow: auto">
<table id="maintable">

    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">

            <th class="th_Jan">Jan</th>
            <th class="th_Feb">Feb</th>
            <th class="th_Mar">Mar</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >

<tr> 
<td>Jan</td>
<td>Feb</td>
<td>Mar</td>

<tr>

<tr> 
<td>Jan1</td>
<td>Feb1</td>
<td>Mar1</td>

<tr>
<tr> 
<td>Jan2</td>
<td>Feb2</td>
<td>Mar2</td>
<tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>



<div id="clonediv" class="ui-widget" style="width: 100%; height: 275px; overflow: auto"></div>





$( "#new" )
.button()
.click(function() {

 $("#maindiv").clone().appendTo($("#clonediv"));

});
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: How does that change your main table anyways? http://jsfiddle.net/88wUZ/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var clone_id = $("#maindiv").clone();
clone_id.attr('id','clone_div');
clone_id.appendTo($("#clonediv"));
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to use this jQuery and see if it fixes your problem.

```
$("#maindiv").clone().prop("id", "mainClone").appendTo($("#clonediv"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
    $("#new").click(function () {

```
$("#maindiv").clone().appendTo($("#clonediv"));

});
```

Demo
    http://jsfiddle.net/zFe5Y/